# Set an SqlDecimal variable to the max value it can store

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

In a certain scenario, I have to set in .net code the value of a decimal variable to a very high value so I use Decimal.MaxValue. Unfortunately, the value of the variable will be saved to the DB on a decimal(18,6) field and when that happens I obviously end up with an arithmetic overflow error.

I don't wan't to hardcode the variable value to 999999999999.999999 so I was wondering if there would be a way to set an instance of a SqlDecimal to the largest number it can handle and then get the Decimal value from it.
For example, I can instantiate an SqlDecimal like this:

```
SqlDecimal sqldec = new SqlDecimal(18,6,true, new int[]{0});
```

but don't know if I can set it to the max value that can be stored in this instance without hardcoding to the value above.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Like Int and Double and other numeric types, there is a MaxValue property. Use it.

Comment: The MaxValue property does not work on instances

Comment: Why do you "have to set the value to a very high value"? That sounds like a problem that could easily be solved by using a type better suited for the task (for example, if it's supposed to mean "not assigned", you could use a nullable decimal).

Comment: I am using the value in imbricated Math.Min comparisons and I need it to be as high as possible. Legacy code, can't really change it in another manner

Comment: @vicch you don't need to use instance if the only thing you're interested is the max available value.

Comment: It's good that you don't want to hardcode 999999999999999999.999999 since it's higher than a `decimal(18,6)` can store. 18 is the *total* number of digits it can hold, either side of the decimal.

Comment: @Alex, the max available value of SqlDecimal is higher than the value that   can be stored in my DB table which has a decimal(18,6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the maximum binary representation of a SqlDecimal of a given precision and scale use :

```
SqlDecimal.Parse("".PadRight(precision-scale,'9')+"."+"".PadRight(scale,'9'));
```

For example for decimal(18,6):

```
public static readonly SqlDecimal MaxDecimal18_6 = SqlDecimal.Parse("".PadRight(18-6,'9')+"."+"".PadRight(6,'9'));
```

To make your boot faster you can take a look at _maxDecimal18_6.Data array in debug mode and convert the previous line to :

```
public static readonly SqlDecimal MaxDecimal18_6 = new SqlDecimal(18, 6, true, -1486618625, 232830643, 0, 0);
```

For a better understanding the precision+scale give the maximum number of digits. These digits are stored as a maximum of 38 decimal digits in a 128 bits binary number (accessed via Data as a four int array). You should notice that each precision+scale give a distinct maximum value and because a 128 bit number may be greater than (10^39)-1 = 999999 .... 38 times, it is impossible to use `new SqlDecimal(38,6,true, -1, -1, -1, -1);` to obtain the highest value (-1 signed gives all bits to one) because this initializer is higher than the highest decimal value.